# zeromq 4.0 with openpgm: How can i use "pgm_setsockopt" to change PGM_MULTICAST_LOOP

Tags: zeromq

I try to change a socket option (PGM_MULTICAST_LOOP) in zeromq with openpgm support. There is a dedicated function 'pgm_setsockopt' to do that but its first argument is a pgm_sock_t * and my original socket is a void * obtained by pSubscriber = zsocket_new(_pZmqContext_X, ZMQ_SUB);
If I call 'pgm_setsockopt' by casting pSubscriber  to (pgm_sock_t *) it does not work.
The question is: how do I "transform" a zsocket_new result pointer into a pgm_sock_t socket which can be used to call 'pgm_setsockopt'

Thanks